# excel vba move multiple files using listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have created a form with three list boxes. The first loads with the files in a selected folder. I then select several files in the first list and move them into the second list box. The files in the second list box now need to be copied into folders listed in the third list box. All the issues of setting the source and destination paths are done. I need the lines of code which cause the selected files in the second list to be copied to the selected destination in the third list box.

Sample code:

```
FileToCopy = FileSourceDirectory & lstSelectedFiles.Value
DestinationFolderName = UserRepositoryDirectory & lstRepositoryFolders
CopiedFile = DestinationFolderName & "\" & lstSelectedFiles.Value
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileCopy FileToCopy, CopiedFile Unload frmCopyFileToRepository
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What doesn't work for you? More precisely, what is the question you want answered?

Comment: You will probably use `MoveFile` after creating a `FileSystemObject`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251462.aspx

Comment: Moving a single file is not the problem.

Comment: I have code, which works, to copy one file at a time.                            FileToCopy = FileSourceDirectory & lstSelectedFiles.Value

DestinationFolderName = UserRepositoryDirectory & lstRepositoryFolders

CopiedFile = DestinationFolderName & "\" & lstSelectedFiles.Value


Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FileCopy FileToCopy, CopiedFile
Unload frmCopyFileToRepository

Comment: I need to be able to select some of the files (from a multi-select list box) and simultaneously move all of then. I have coded selecting files from the full list (first list box) and moving them to the second list box. I need the code to copy all the files in the second list box to the destination folder

Comment: Took the sample code from a comment and embedded it in the original post - it's much easier to read that way

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer
 For i = 0 To lstSelectedFiles.ListCount - 1

  FileToCopy = FileSourceDirectory & lstSelectedFiles.List(i)

      CopiedFile = DestinationFolderName & "\" & lstSelectedFiles.List(i)

  Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FileCopy FileToCopy, CopiedFile

Next i
```